# Confusion in Levi-Civita indices.

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

I have a confusion lowering and raising in Levi-Civita indices. I don't understand which of the following relation is correct.
$$\epsilon^{ijk} = \epsilon_{ijk}$$
or
$$\epsilon^{ijk} = - \epsilon_{ijk}$$

Where I am using metric $ diag(1.-1) $. Also tell me if there is some link between metric tensor and Levi-Civita tensor. I am putting a snap from some book on covariant formalism of electromagnetism.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Properties): In a context where tensor index notation is used to manipulate tensor components, the Levi-Civita symbol may be written with its indices as either subscripts or superscripts with no change in meaning, as might be convenient. Thus, one could write

$$\varepsilon^{ij\dots k}=\varepsilon_{ij\dots k}
$$

You can see that it is not called "tensor", in which case it would need the metric tensor to raise/lower its indices, but "symbol". It is just a synthetic way to express a collection of $0, 1, -1$ depending of the value and order of the indeces.

Comment: Thank you for response. But I have seen $ \epsilon^{ijk} = - \epsilon_{ijk} $. Can I send you a pdf file so you may see it?

Comment: Sure, send it at my name + gmail_com, but I have to warn you that I am very rusty about this topics. You may prefer publishing it here so that many others can see it.

Comment: Also in covariant formalism it is used as $ \epsilon ^{\mu\nu\rho} $ and its a tensor there.

Comment: How to publish a reference from a book? Should I paste a snap?

Comment: I have edited my q and pasted pic, also gonna send you pdf file. Thank you.

Comment: I see... I guess that, being a symbol introduced for sake of conciseness, as long as it is coherently used throuout the text it can be defined with that feature. My last suggestion is to report the question on physics.SE, there you are sure to find people with experience on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the metric $dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2$? If so, you change sign every time you raise/lower a spacelike index in Minkowski coordinates - for example, your screenshot includes the equation $B_k = -B^k$. Since $\epsilon$ has three indices, raising/lowering all three changes the sign by $(-1)^3 = -1$.

Comment: @lesath82: I'm not sure what you mean - the definition clearly states that $-\epsilon^{ijk} = +1$ and thus $\epsilon^{ijk} = -1$ in that case.

Comment: you're right, I'm deleting my oversight